# How to implement spell checker functionality on text box in JSF (RichFaces)?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to implement spell check functionality on text box in jsf 1.2 rich faces.
I had implemented this on text area using rich editor tag  ...but having a hard time to implement the spell check button functionality on text box .

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with the following code:

```
<h:inputTextarea id="tac" rows="5" cols="90"
    value="#{chWebConfig.tacContent}" lang="en">
        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render="tacOutputPanel" />
</h:inputTextarea>
```

Important part for you is **`lang="en"`**.

Second example:

```
<h:inputTextarea id="receiptMessage" label="#{msg.receiptMessage}"
    lang="en" value="#{promotion.receiptMessage}" rows="5" cols="80">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" />
</h:inputTextarea>
```